# Saving a file that has been opened by a particular process in C#

Tags: c#, regex, batch-file, process, file-extension

I'm working with a filetype that doesn't exist in the public domain. The file is in binary or hex, but there's been a previous batch file written that runs when you double click on a file in order to open it as a .txt file in notepad.

What I am trying to do is to open this file within my program, and then save it while it is open so that it is now a .txt file, and I can work with it.

So I start the batch file process and the file itself is the argument.

```
/*Start the  batch file and open file (as an argument)
         * Then it'll be viewable as a text file 
         * */
        Process process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo.FileName = "C:/batchfile.bat";
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = "C:/file.ext";
        process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        process.Start();
```

I then look to see if any of the current running processes have the file extension and are running in notepad, using Regex:

```
/*Using a regex pattern, we can see if a wtd file has been opened
         * If there is, it's added to an array called matchArr
         * */

String pattern = "^.*ext.*Notepad.*$";
        Regex rgx = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses();
        int useMatch = 0;
        String[] matchArr = new String[100];
        foreach (var proc in processes)
        {
            MatchCollection matches = rgx.Matches(proc.MainWindowTitle);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))

                if (matches.Count > 0)
                {

                    useMatch = matches.Count;
                    for (int i = 0; i < useMatch; i++)
                    {
                        matchArr[i] = proc.MainWindowTitle;
                        String blah = proc.Modules[0].FileName;
                        string path = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(proc.MainWindowTitle);

                        Console.WriteLine("Path:" +path);
                        StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(blah);
                        FileStream fstr = new FileStream("C:/newName.txt", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
                        using (StreamWriter strw = new StreamWriter(fstr))
                        {
                            strw.WriteLine(stream);
                            Console.WriteLine("Array is : " + matchArr[i].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
        }
```

I've been Googling all day - I must be going wrong somewhere in my approach, but I didn't think it should be so difficult to figure this out. Any help would be much appreciated - I'm not native to C# either, so excuse any bad coding practices.

Can anybody help me to figure out how to change this file to a .txt file? Also, C# obviously doesn't read it as .txt so I can't just change the file extension as in Notepad, which is why I'm trying to do it this way. I also spent a lot of time messing around with encoding but to no avail.

Comment: What does your batch file do?

Comment: Hi, I didn't write the batch file myself (I've never written one, actually) but basically what it does is when you try to open one of the files, it finds the latest version of that file and starts Notepad in order to read it - there's another batch file that converts it into readable form (I think) - that's all I know, apologies!

Comment: I would recommend that you modify the batch file to not start notepad but to do something else with it instead. If you include the batch file in your post, maybe someone can help you with that.

Comment: Hi, I don't really feel comfortable adding the batch file, as it's not my work so I'll have to try and figure it out without that - I appreciate the suggestion, though.

Answer (score 0):

If it's binary you can convert it to text this way and save it:

```
string myString;
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(YourBinaryFile, FileMode.Open))
using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs))
{
    byte[] bin = br.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
    myString = Convert.ToBase64String(bin);
}
```

Then you could write it to a file this way:

```
File.WriteAllText(YourTargetTxtFile, myString);
```

Or use it as you see fit.
Hope that helps!

Edit:

You can specify encoding using this function as well, overloaded:

```
File.WriteAllText(file, contents, encoding);
```

Comment: Chris - I have tried that already (extensively :) ) and it does not work; I think the fact that it's ANSI is part of the problem there. Basically, it saves it all right, but it encodes it in gobbledygook. So I can't use that either. Hence, why I'm trying the really complex way of doing it!

Thanks for trying though, it's much appreciated.

Comment: Oh, I understand now.  I thought you were doing it very complexly- but perhaps you shouldn't try to invent the wheel.  Have you tried to specify the encoding?  Updating my answer.

Comment: Hi, yes I have and still no luck! Still random characters in the txt file that's created. I'm really at a loss with how to do this; it shouldn't be so difficult. Perhaps it has to do with the original file type - as I said, it's a private extension so that's possibly why the encoding gets screwed!

Comment: Well the extension is simply an identifier for the OS.  It doesn't change how C# interacts with it- that's entirely up to you.  BUT it could mean that the file is not simply text.  You may have to decode it or convert it somehow before you save it to a simple text file in C#.

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can find out simply what kind of data is in the file? Thanks for your help so far!